# String handle in C#

Tags: c#

I don't understand the use of "get" and "set" command, how to add a list of the accounts using the code below and someone give me some example to fix the error? Thanks! :(

```
    public class Account
    {

        public string UserName

        {get rerurn textBox1.Test; // error
        set UserName = textBox1.Text;} // error

        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string RePassword { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string bd { get; set; }
        public string dt { get; set; }
        public string dc { get; set; }
    }
    public class ListAcc
    {
        static void Data()
        {
            List<Account> UserList = new List<Account>();
        }
    }
```

Okey, thanks everybody, i had fixed that error but if code:

```
 public class ListAcc
        {
            static void Data()
            {
                List<Account> UserList = new List<Account>();
                //example of adding user account
                Account acc = new Account();
                acc.Username = textBox1.Text;
                UserList.Add(acc);
            }
        }
```

there are a error from access to textBox1.Text? ( An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property)... Someone can help?

Comment: Many thanks! Now i have this problem! >.<

error CS0038: Cannot access a nonstatic member of outer type'...'via nested type '...'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change UserName method to

```
 public string UserName
    {

            get { return textBox1.Text;}
            set { textBox1.Text = value;} 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. There's no 'textBox1' field in Account class - I think that You copied that from some other code.
2. spelling error: there should be 'return' not rerurn

   ```
   public class Account
   {    
       public string UserName {get; set;}             
       public string Password { get; set; }
       public string RePassword { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string bd { get; set; }
       public string dt { get; set; }
       public string dc { get; set; }
   }
   public class ListAcc
   {
       static void Data()
       {
           List<Account> UserList = new List<Account>();
           //example of adding user account
           Account acc = new Account();
           acc.UserName ="John Doe";
           UserList.Add(acc);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You don't want to tightly couple the model to the UI anyway.

Comment: how to get string value in a textbox? many error {get; set;} ... :(

Answer (score 0):

The get and set should be enclosed with curly braces { }, you also typed "rerun" instead of "return", to fix it, change the Username property to:

```
public string UserName
{
        get 
        {  
             return textBox1.Text; 
        }
        set 
        {  
             textBox1.Text = value;
        } 
}
```

Note:  make sure your class has access to the "textBox1" control

Answer (score 0):

```
publuc string variableName
{
 get{ return _variableName;}
 set{ _variableName=value;}
}
```

get and set are getters and setters for the property so when ever you call this property the value returned by return in your  get is what you get.

when ever you assign any value to the property it gets assigned to the variable to which you say variableName=value;

```
  publuc string variableName
    {
     get;
     set;
    }
```

when ever you dont want to directly expose any variable(private) you can make property of it using varable names in getter and setter, otherwise mere get;set; will do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your Form a new Textbox and be sure it is called TextBox1, then your first example will work.

> public class Account 
>       {
>
> ```
>     public string UserName 
>
>     {get rerurn textBox1.Test; // error 
>     set UserName = textBox1.Text;} // error 
>
>     public string Password { get; set; } 
>     public string RePassword { get; set; } 
>     public string Name { get; set; } 
>     public string bd { get; set; } 
>     public string dt { get; set; } 
>     public string dc { get; set; } 
> } 
> public class ListAcc 
> { 
>     static void Data() 
>     { 
>         List<Account> UserList = new List<Account>(); 
>     } 
> }  Okey, thanks everybody, i had fixed that error but if code:
> ```
>
> public class ListAcc 
>           { 
>               static void Data() 
>               { 
>                   List UserList = new List(); 
>                   //example of adding user account 
>                   Account acc = new Account(); 
>                   acc.Username = textBox1.Text; 
>                   UserList.Add(acc); 
>               } 
>           }